# Prove or Disprove: $(A\cap B)\cap(A\cap D)^c = A\cap(B\cap D^c)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to prove or disprove:

$$(A\cap B)\cap(A\cap D)^c = A\cap(B\cap D^c)$$

Any help would be appreciate. Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I've figured that A intersects B, and that A intersects D, and that these two intersections intersect each other. I feel lost and google is not helping, any tips or steps in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> $\begin{align}(A\cap B)\cap(A\cap D)^c &=(A\cap B)\cap(A^c \cup D^c)\\&=(A\cap B\cap A^c)\cup (A\cap B\cap D^c)\\&=\emptyset \,\cup (A\cap B\cap D^c) \\&= A\cap (B\cap D^c). \end{align}$

Try to attempt the answer without using my solution and make use of $A \cap (B \cup C )= (A \cap B ) \cup (A \cap C )$ and $(A \cap B)^c = (A^c \cup B^c)$ and that $A \cap (B\cap C)=A \cap B \cap C$.

Comment: Will do! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Venn Diagram for the Q]

The yellow region is the intersection $A \cap B$. What is $(A \cap D)^C$? And so on.

Drawing the Venn diagram should resolve any confusions pre or post the set algebra.

Answer (score 0):

Apply DeMorgan's Law to the LHS:

$(A\cap B)\cap(A\cap D)^c = (A\cap B) \cap (A^c \cup D^c)...$

Distribute the intersection over union:

$...= (A\cap B \cap A^c) \cup (A\cap B \cap D^c)$

Note that $A\cap A^c = \varnothing$

$... = \varnothing \cup (A\cap B\cap D^c) = A \cap (B \cap D^c)\ \ \ \ \mathrm{(QED)}$

since the position of the brackets don't matter when you have a chain of the same operation (associativity).